# Combine INSERT INTO and SELECT on MySQL

Tags: mysql

Step 1) Find the *id*s in *users* table that does not exist in players table.
Step 2) Insert into players table with those missing *id*s

So I should combine these two queries. (Giving the result of the SELECT query as a list to the INSERT INTO query)

```
SELECT users.uid 
FROM users 
WHERE users.uid NOT IN (select uid from players);

INSERT INTO players (uid)
VALUES ()
```

What is the cleanest way to do this?

Comment: use insert into <table> select .... syntax https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place your select query below the insert query and remove `values()`:

```
INSERT INTO players (uid)
SELECT users.uid 
FROM users 
WHERE users.uid NOT IN (select uid from players);
```

**EDIT Based On Comments**
An easy way would be to use `INSERT IGNORE` - This will basically insert all the `uid` that are not in the `players`'s table and ignore the rest:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO players (uid)
SELECT users.uid 
FROM users
```

Comment: Well insert ignore would be simpler

Comment: @Strawberry thanks, I updated my answer, is that okay with you?

Comment: Fine with me! But it doesn't need to be PRIMARY. It just needs to be UNIQUE!

Comment: Oops - your previous answer was better! It really does need to be UNIQUE (if it's not PRIMARY)

Comment: @Strawberry _"all the uid that do not exist in that table and ignore the rest"_ I think this line explains that the query will insert unique values

Comment: But that's not what it does. It ignores them because that column is set as  unique (or primary)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO users (uid)
(SELECT users.uid
   FROM users
   LEFT JOIN players ON users.uid = players.uid)
   WHERE players.uid IS null)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO players 
SELECT users.uid 
FROM users 
WHERE users.uid NOT IN (select uid from players);
```